# How to load custom font in FontFactory.register in iText

Tags: java, fonts, pdf-generation, itext

I need your help in adding a custom font "arial.ttf" which is stored under the resources folder in my project in the `FontFactory.register` method in iText.

The font path is as follows in the project from Windows Explorer:

> public_html\resources\fonts\arial.ttf

The code for referring to the font is:

```
FontFactory.register("/resources/fonts/arial.ttf", "my_bold_font");
Font myBoldFont = FontFactory.getFont("my_bold_font");
```

However when I ran the Java method, it always gives me the error:

> java.io.IOException: /resources/fonts/arial.ttf not found as file or
>   resource.

I tried with different paths for example:

> /public_html/resources/fonts/arial.ttf
>
> ../resources/fonts/arial.ttf
>
> /fonts/arial.ttf
>
> /arial.ttf

But the result is the same that the file can't be found. So how to refer to the file?

Comment: are trying in server?

Comment: @Satya yes I am trying to do that in the server

Comment: linux based or win based

Comment: @Satya I will be deploying the project to WAR and will be deploying it in Linux server. However I want to test it in my local weblogic as well.

Comment: `getServletContext().getRealPath(File.separator)+File.separator+"resources"+File.separator+"fonts"+File.separator+"arial.ttf"`

Comment: @Satya should I replace the full path "/resources/fonts/arial.ttf" with the above one?

Comment: @Satya it gave error starting from getServletContext()

Comment: @Satya I did the code :  FontFactory.register(getServletContext().getRealPath(File.separator)+File.separator+"resources"+File‌​.separator+"fonts"+File.separator+"arial.ttf", "my_bold_font"); and it gave an error that Not a valid expression statement

Comment: Oh! where you are writing this code means in normal java or in servlets

Comment: @Satya in Normal Java Method

Comment: FontFactory.register("resources"+File‌​.separator+"fonts"+File.separator+"arial.ttf", "my_bold_font");

Comment: @Satya File.separator is not recognized and it is giving that it is not a valid expression

Comment: no. try `System.getProperty("file.separator")`

Comment: don't copy and paste. type it. sometimes special characters will be added. But both are correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84806/discussion-between-99maas-and-satya).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the path of the 'font' which are present in the resources folder, using `contextClassLoader` and can be used in the `FontFactory` file path.

```
URL font_path = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("fontname");
FontFactory.register(font_path.toString(), "test_font");
```

I have tested this code and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

The code was done by:

```
 FontFactory.register(System.getProperty("file.separator")+"resources"+System.getProperty("file.separator")+"fonts"+System.getProperty("file.separator")+"arial.‌​ttf", "my_bold_font");
 Font myBoldFont = FontFactory.getFont("my_bold_font");
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this for adding all fonts that are stored in a folder  "src/main/webapp/resources/fonts" to the XMLWorkerFontProvider.

It worked successfully.

```
XMLWorkerFontProvider fontImp = new XMLWorkerFontProvider(XMLWorkerFontProvider.DONTLOOKFORFONTS);

URL font_path = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("resources/fonts");

File directory = new File(font_path.getPath());

//get all the files from a directory

File[] fList = directory.listFiles();

for (File file : fList){

    System.out.println("Font File Path******************************   " +file.getPath());
    fontImp.register(file.getPath());
} 
FontFactory.setFontImp(fontImp);

Document document = new Document();
Rectangle one = new Rectangle(width,height);
document.setPageSize(one);
document.setMargins(1, 1, 1, 1);
ByteArrayOutputStream bos1 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PdfWriter pdfWriter=PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(folderPath+"/"+fileName));
document.open();

InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(html.getBytes());
//XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(pdfWriter,document, is);
XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(pdfWriter,document, is, null, null,fontImp);
document.close();
```

Answer (score -1):

I am using Spring Boot 2.2 with iText 5 (openpdf) and this code is working well when I execute the Spring Boot app.

```
import com.lowagie.text.Font;
import com.lowagie.text.FontFactory;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.BaseFont;
import java.awt.*;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.core.io.ResourceLoader;

public class CustomFont {

    public static Font myFont;

    /**
     * This method should be loaded when you start the app for the first time.
     * @param resourceLoader The resource you can get using Spring @Autowired annotation and passing it to here.
     */
    public static void registerFont(ResourceLoader resourceLoader) {

        try {

            // Note the "classpath: " syntax.
            // I am storing my font in: src/main/resources/fonts/my-custom-font.ttf
            Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:/fonts/my-custom-font.ttf");
            FontFactory.register(resource.getURL().getPath(), "aliasCustomFontName");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // When executing the unit tests, the font is not found so I am catching and ignoring it.
            // The fonts are not important for the unit tests in my case.
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        myFont = FontFactory.getFont("aliasCustomFontName", BaseFont.WINANSI, true, 1, Font.NORMAL, Color.WHITE);
    }

    /**
     * You can use the custom font in your code with: CustomFont.myFont
     */

}
```