# Reading text from pdf with iText7 + C#, text not recognized

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

i want to read data from pdf document. I use iText7:

```
var src = "<file location>";
var pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(src));
var strategy = new LocationTextExtractionStrategy();
for (int i = 1; i <= pdfDocument.GetNumberOfPages(); ++i)
{
     var page = pdfDocument.GetPage(i);
     string text = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(page, strategy);
     string processed = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ASCIIEncoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(text)));
}
pdfDocument.Close();
```

It works, but doesn't recognize letters. All text looks like

"����������\n�������������������������\n�����������������������������������\n

It is in English, so I don't expect any problems with encoding. What is the cause of this issue and how can I fix it?

Comment: You don't need the text conversion. Can you extract text with Acrobat? If you can´t, it's game over.

Comment: @PauloSoares what do you mean by 'with acrobat'?

Comment: Adobe Acrobat Reader.  Can you copy&paste the text having opened that pdf in Adobe Reader? Please share the pdf in question for analysis.

Comment: @dariaamir did you manage to solve this issue?

Comment: @AdvanTiSS unfortunately, no. Issue was caused by a custom proprietary font, that was used in that document. I tried a few different libraries, but neither was able to read it.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the conversion you're doing. Change the code to:

```
StringBuilder processed = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 1; i <= pdfDocument.GetNumberOfPages(); ++i)
    {
         var page = pdfDocument.GetPage(i);
         string text = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(page, strategy);
         processed.Append(text);
    }
```

Comment: I receive the same text there
����������\n�������������������������\n

Comment: @dariaamir while the issue with your document is a different one, you should indeed drop that conversion thing. It looks like it will only do harm and never anything helpful. Or can you explain why you use it?

Comment: As others have commented, does the pdf file display the expected text when opened in adobe acrobat reader?

Comment: @auburg yes, I can see it in acrobat reader. Seems, that the issue is with a custom font, that is used in this exact pdf....

Comment: See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746950/how-to-load-custom-font-in-fontfactory-register-in-itext